# Storing Enviornment Variables using Service Workers

Tags: vue.js, service-worker

The problem: I can't have my service worker access my .env variables

The only solution I found was storing the variables into a generated js files, I am using **Vue PWA** for this.

**Vue** Config

```js
module.exports = {
  pwa: {
    name: 'Fintask App',
    themeColor: '#3aa9ff',
    msTileColor: '#3aa9ff',
    appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
    appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'black',
 
    // configure the workbox plugin
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      // swSrc is required in InjectManifest mode.
      swSrc: 'src/service-worker.js',
      // ...other Workbox options...
    }
  }
};
```

My service worker config

```js
importScripts('swenv.js'); // this generates an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'process' before initialization

workbox.setConfig({
   debug: false,
 });
 
 workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);

 workbox.routing.registerRoute(
   new RegExp(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ROOT_URL}/organization/(.*)`),
   workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
     cacheName: 'organization',
   }),
 );
```

my swEnvBuild that should generate my swenv.js

```js
//swEnvBuild.js - script that is separate from webpack
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFileSync("public/swenv.js",
   `const process = {
      env: {
        VUE_APP_API_ROOT_URL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_ROOT_URL
      }
    }`);
```

my swenv.js

```js
const process = {
      env: {
        VUE_APP_API_ROOT_URL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_ROOT_URL
      }
    }
```

This is still not working for me, I did find different solutions based on this method, I just wish there was a better way

My output

```
swenv.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'process' before initialization
    at swenv.js:3
    at service-worker.js:3

Error during service worker registration: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost/') with script ('http://localhost/service-worker.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed
```

Don't know why I get this error, this result was generated in my apache server

Comment: why do you want env variables into the sw?

Comment: so I can add different environments, I have 2 active servers, one of them being homologation and the other being production

Comment: Hey, did you solve it,  I am looking for a solution to this problem too

Comment: Yea my issue was because my staging environment wasn't set to staging, it was as development. Check your env.staging and set node_env to staging. You can access them threw registerServiceWorker.js